# Let $F/K$ be a field extension and $a\in F$ such that $[K(a):K]$ is odd

Tags: field-theory

Let $F/K$ be a field extension and $a\in F$ such that $[K(a):K]$ is odd. Prove that $K\left(a\right)=K\left(a^{2}\right)$ and give counterexample if $[K(a):K]$ is even.

Comment: Hint: $K \subset K(a^2) \subset K(a)$. Use the degree formula.

Comment: It seem to be answered here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77769/equal-simple-field-extensions
But I want a counterexample if $[K(a):K]$ is even

Comment: @chuyenvien94 Consider $F=\mathbb{R}, K=\mathbb{Q}, a=\sqrt{2}$. Claeraly, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\not= \mathbb{Q}((\sqrt{2})^2)$

Comment: Oh, of course. Thank you.

Comment: @chuyenvien94 Would you answer you own question with the comments you and other have made?